# NewRelic PHP Zend Framework Transactions All Start with "NoModule"

Tags: newrelic

We're using NewRelic, and all our Zend Framework (1.11.x) PHP pages are showing up as "/NoModule/page/index".   We're curious to know where the "NoModule" is coming from, as it doesn't show up anywhere in the code base.

Answer (score 1):

For the Zend Framework, the New Relic PHP agent names web requests with "module/controller/action" using information parsed from the Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract parameter to Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker::routeShutdown. If no module is found, "NoModule" is used for the module name. This is known behavior, which should be better reflected in our documentation.